# How can I register a WCF service programmatically within an IIS environment

Tags: wcf, c#-3.0, iis-7.5

Let's say we have 2 projects with following layout

- Project "web"

  - global.asax (I thought of this destination for registration within eg `void Application_Start(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e`)
  - web.config
- Project "wcf"

  - DemoService.cs
  - IDemoService.cs

`web.config` would look like this

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="fooBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="wcf.DemoService"
                     behaviorConfiguration="fooBehavior">
                <endpoint address="mex"
                          binding="mexHttpBinding"
                          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="wsHttpBinding"
                          contract="wcf.IDemoService" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

So ... now ... somewhere (as mentioned above I thought of `global.asax`) I need to register, that when browsing to *URI* `wcf.DemoService`get's resolved and for a mex-request the `wcf.IDemoService` gets resolved for reading the attributes to get a WSDL.

This would usually be done by creating a `.svc` file and put header in the first line, e.g.:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="wcf.DemoService" %>
```

In e.g. a console application by

```
var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof (wcf.DemoService));
serviceHost.Open();
```

And combine this with a `host` element within the `service` element to specify the *URI* - or use another ctor-overload of `ServiceHost`

But I would rather go for a static registration (or any `web.config` registration which works for IIS 7.5) - is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? The title of your question looks unrelated to the last paragraph.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka not really: a typical WCF-in-IIS-hosting is realized by using a .svc-file (I've added an example for that) - but instead of realizing the hosting with a .svc-file I would rather go for a _static_ (_URI_ not changeable unless eg recompile - in contrast to just moving the .svc-file) registration within `global.asax` or within the `web.config` (eg. if i add a `host`-element to the `service`-element with an address, I'll get an access-denied exception)

Comment: .svc file is already static because you must be and admin of the web server to be able to rename it and if you are admin of the web server you can change the configuration file and sometimes even global.asax (if inlined) as well. Can you use .NET 4.0? Because it offers what you want but .NET 3.5 doesn't.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka jep, but a .svc-file isn't a _parameterized static_ approach (thanks for asking for a more detailed formulation!) - eg using config-values for certain paths. another reason for not using .svc-files: what if i want to register a service from another layer (eg some web-helper assembly) - no chance for that ... even if i have to use .NET 3.5 mandatory, it would be *reeeeeaaaallyyy* awesome if you'd add a solution for .NET 4.0 - maybe I can use the .NET 4.0-approach for another project ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WCF 4 (.NET 4.0) offers both code based registration of services and configuration based registration of services.

Code based configuration is achieved through ASP.NET Routing by new [`ServiceRoute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.serviceroute.aspx):

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("DemoService", 
                          new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(wcf.DemoService));
```

Routes are usually used with REST services but it works for SOAP services as well.

Registering service in configuration is called [configuration based activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807499.aspx). You will define virtual .svc file in web.config:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
   <serviceActivation>
      <add relativeAddress="DemoService.svc" service="wcf.DemoService" />
   </serviceActivation>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

In both cases you are defining only relative path to your service because base address is always specified by your web site hosted in IIS.

Comment: thanks, this one is awesome! even if it is not working before .NET 4.0 ... :(